# У меня проблема с инициализацией Firebase в Quasar framework

Tags: vue.js, firebase

Пожалуйста, подскажите как правильно инициализировать firebase в quasar. Я создал файл firebase.js в папке ./boot, также  добавил firebase в quasar.conf.js. Но почему то все равно не работает. Ошибок в консоли никаких нет, материалов тоже мало по этому поводу.

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/database'
export default function () {
  const app = {
    created () {
      var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: 'xxx',
        authDomain: 'xxx',
        databaseURL: 'xxx',
        projectId: 'xxx',
        storageBucket: 'xxx',
        messagingSenderId: 'xxx',
        appId: 'xxx',
        measurementId: 'xxx'
      }
      // Initialize Firebase
      firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
      firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
          this.$store.dispatch('autoLoginUser', user)
        }
      })
      this.$store.dispatch('fetchProducts')
    }
  }
  return {
    app
  }
}
```

Comment: Можно инициализировать в хуке главного компонента приложения - именно так я и делаю (когда фреймворкоспецифичные заморочки мешают, их можно обходить). Главное структурировать проект, используя модули, чтобы огромных трудночитаемых файлов не было... ну и не нарушать принципы Vue. Использование хука для таких целей, их не нарушает.

Comment: @yar85 И правда так работает! Спасибо)